# How can I get an element of a sequence?

Tags: functions, sequence

How can I get an element of a sequence?
For example `Sequence[a,b,c,d]`
How can get `c`?

Comment: Wrap it in a list and then take parts of that list?

Comment: @J.M. yes, I did that before but was wondering if that is how people normally do it.

Comment: `Part` is more natural. But you can also use `Slot`: i.e.,  `#3 &@Sequence[a, b, c, d]`.

Comment: With `Part` are you talking about the method that  J. M. mentioned above?
@kglr

Comment: that's right...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
seq = Sequence[a, b, c, d]
```

> ```
> Sequence[a, b, c, d]
> ```

You can use a composition of  `Part ([[...]])` and `List` as suggested by J.M.'sennui:

```
{seq}[[3]]
```

> ```
> c
> ```

```
(Part[#, 3] & @* List)[seq]
```

> ```
> c
> ```

Alternatively, you can use `Slot[3]` (that is, `#3`):

```
#3 & @ seq
```

> ```
> c
> ```

```
Slot[3] &[seq]
```

> ```
> c
> ```

Comment: Is there any advantage of writing `(Part[#, 3] & @* List)[seq]` instead of `{seq}[[3]]`?

Comment: @anhnha, can't think of  any.